# How to enable multiple user accounts on an iPad, to be used by a family

Tags: ipad, user-account, mdm, fast-user-switching

I'm trying to set up a new iPad 9 to be used by me, my wife, and our kid, all under their own user accounts at the iOS level. I know it's not straightforward to do this, but I'm trying to do it using [Shared iPad](https://support.apple.com/guide/deployment/shared-ipad-overview-dep9a34c2ba2/web). I'm somewhat familiar with the concept of MDM, but most of this is new and confusing to me.

I signed up for ManageEngine Mobile Device Manager Plus, installed an MDM profile on the iPad,

[image: screenshot of MDM profile installed on iPad]

and followed the first part of [ManageEngine's documentation on Apple Enrollment using Apple Configurator](https://www.manageengine.com/mobile-device-management/help/enrollment/enroll_ios_devices_using_apple_configurator.html#How_to_enroll_iOS_devices_with_MDM_using_Apple_Configurator), even though I'm not sure how much of it applies to what I'm trying to do. When I got to the "prepare devices" step, I saw that the "Enable shared iPad" checkbox was disabled, and I'm not sure why, so I stopped there.

[image: Apple Configurator - prepare devices screenshot]

What is the simplest path to enabling multiple user accounts on this iPad? I don't have Apple School Manager, Business Manager, or Business Essentials. Most of the documentation I'm finding is for school or business settings.

Mac OS 14.3, Apple Configurator 2.17

iPad 9, iPadOS 17.1

Comment: Apple's iPads only support multiple user accounts in a special education mode intended for schools.